# How to exit the elm repl?

Tags: elm, read-eval-print-loop

I am learning [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/), and need to be able to exit the elm repl. I tried `exit()` like python, `\q` like postgres, typing just `exit` like MySQL, even `:q` like Haskell. The only thing I can do is close the terminal to exit, there has to be a better way.

Comment: Elm Repl can behave strangely on some linux distros - if you're using one. For example, if you cannot clear the screen with CTRL + L or you cannot easily go back and delete, then you'll have to make a manual fix for this problem. IT is worth double checking that as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To exit the `elm repl` you need to type `:exit`. You can also use `Ctrl + d`, but I prefer typed commands instead of multi-key holds. I found this answer [here](https://elmprogramming.com/elm-repl.html) as part of the (unofficial) getting started with elm programming guide.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more detail, after launching the REPL in your terminal/command line, you are prompted to visit the elm-lang site for further information regarding use of the interactive shell:

> To exit the REPL, you can type `:exit`.
>
> You can also press `ctrl-d` or `ctrl-c` on some platforms.
>
> -- https://elm-lang.org/0.19.0/repl

Just for future reference, Evan (Elm's creator) has created a trove of 'hints' in the [elm/compiler](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/hints) repo.